# WAMP 2.2e - 403 Forbidden in Offline and Online mode

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, php, mysql, wamp

I just installed a WAMP Server 2.2e, wamp icon in tray is green, showing - **Wamp server is offline**. When i'am trying to access my localhost address, i receive an error 403 Forbidden.
For `localhost`, `localhost/phpmyadmin`, for my `http://192.168.0.10/`, nothing works.

After switching to Online mode, i can access `localhost` and `http://192.168.0.10/`, but not phpmyadmin in both localhost and ipadress mode.

What's the problem ? Nothing is blocking port 80, just made a clean install.

I do not want to put wamp to online mode, i want it to be Offline, but at the same time using all of it's functionalities like in previous versions of Wamp.

Thanks for suggestions and tips in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on the WAMP icon, **Apache** > **Alias Directories** > **localhost/phpmyadmin** > **Edit alias**, and change *Allow from 127.0.0.1* to *Allow from all*

For localhost, click on the WAMP icon, **Apache** > **httpd.conf**. Look for this line

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

change to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
```